# What are the situations where chaos and randomness is necessary evil in the society?

Tags: society, culture, philosophy

Often chaos and randomness are seen as the harbinger of life and contribute towards the development of wide varieties of life forms. My question is what are the different situations where chaos and randomness will be necessary for the maintenance of the world order? I want to know which kind of chaotic situations should be encouraged while which kind should be attenuated.

Specifically, my question asks about ***differences between the Democratic Choas and Autocratic order***. And how can we exploit their best practices in building a new world order?

Comment: We already live in *chaotic* and *random* world *order*, so nothing new

Comment: As of the question now, it is too broad. You should specify the constraints and more specific question.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. Right now your question looks a bit unclear and broad to me. Could you explain what you mean with the maintenance of the world order? As you say chaos and randomness are a normal part of life, so you should state how your world is designed. Otherwise we don't know what kind of world order you are talking about.

Comment: chemistry would not work if not chaotic molecules movements and chaotic changes of their energy(energy of all molecules is different and it different at any given time) due to multiple collisions. Sun would not shine for the same reason.

Comment: The two gods in Brandon Sanderson's _Mistborn_ series are Ruin and Preservation. The Wax and Wayne books in particular examine what happens when there's too much Preservation and not enough Ruin.

Comment: I may not be understanding the question... **Mad Max** = Chaos; **1984** = Order?  I wouldn't want to live in either...

Comment: You can't exploit it, plan it, or control it.  Chaos and order both, the places you *need* it are exactly where people don't *want it*.  You need one to shake the other up, to provide change, to question if there is a better way.  No way that can be exploited, the whole point is that we sometimes have to try things we *don't know* to find things we *didn't know* were better - which of course also means finding things we *didn't know* which were worse!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with whoever stated the question is too broad, but am compelled to answer regardless.

When primitive Chaoman first adopted religion, it was to explain the seemingly randomness of events, by claiming they were controlled by a deity (the RNG in the sky). The hardcore conclusion of this logic was that they could only be sure they were doing the God's will if they relied entirely on chance, wherever possible. Any attempts to subvert this randomness were seen as blasphemy, and over time the populace adapted to embrace chance, not complaining when something goes wrong, but accepting that RNJesus disapproved of what they were attempting to do.

Over the years, the embrace of randomness, as opposed to the minimizing of risk, inevitably resulted in massive failures and massive successes, and the Chaomen became adept at dealing with failure and exploiting success. To them, if something wasn't incredibly risky, it wasn't worth doing, and was disrespectful to that greater power looking over them all. It was thanks to this that their society evolved as quickly as it did, and despite many hurdles (such as when they blew up their moon), they would always find a solution to their problems. Everyone was always pushing some sort of boundary, and dealing with both success and failure, and so the world was at peace.

The unfortunate downfall of the Chaomen occurred when one of their travellers returned from a journey through space, with tales of a society that actively worked against RNJesus, trying to ensure that everything was as risk free as possible. Having lived in their society for a few years, the traveller had embraced this new philosophy, and opened a new church on the homeworld, arguing that risk should be minimized, in favour of orderly progress. By using these new teachings, the new cult spread like wildfire - by managing its risks it was able to outperform the Chaomen in most day to day situations, and despite not making as many technological breakthroughs, it eventually spread to encompass the globe, as people were drawn in by the much greater lifespan of those within, as well as their seemingly content demeanour.

With this, RNJesus was discredited, and the Chaomen began to live stable lives. Their new goal was to eliminate risk, and that meant eliminating anything dangerous to their new lifestyle (animals, professions, ideas, etc). Finally, they succeeded, and never accomplished anything of note ever again, until the species the traveller had met, many years before, showed up on their doorstep. They saw how orderly the Chaomen society had become, and were happy to offer improvements that could make their lives even more efficient and risk free. The Chaomen accepted this, acknowledging that this species had invented the orderly method of living, and that it was far less risky to take their advice than to ignore it, and so they allowed these newcomers to reform their society. Quickly they were no more than slaves, and this lasted for many centuries, as nobody was willing to take the risk of speaking out against their new masters.

Finally, when all hope seemed lost, one of the workers found an ancient tablet, whilst deep down in the gold mines - it spoke of RNJesus, and the power that came from embracing his will. With this, the Chaomen slowly embraced their true nature, and completely devastated the new world order, reintroducing massive levels of chaos into their every action, and throwing off the shackles of risk management. For them, Order was nothing but a tool, used to manipulate them, and leaving them susceptible to the whims of others. Only by embracing their chaotic nature could they thrive, and thrive they did... until they deleted the entire universe, and nobody could really complain about that.

Comment: I lol'd. Well done!

Comment: Well, you've talked about the rise and fall of chaos as well as order. Which partially do quench my query but do you think we can create an equilibrium for both. Is it possible

Comment: I think anything is possible, and that modern society is a fair mix of chaos and order